# Magento 2.4.4 new email syntax

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

Previously I had been using the code below to get the payment method title of an order and placing it in an email

```
     {{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}
```

However, since the upgrade to Magento 2.4.4 this no longer works because of the changes to do with the improved email syntax.

I thought just doing the below would have worked, however when I do that it breaks all emails and nothing sends

```
  {{var order_data.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get an update on this?

Comment: Any update on the above?

Comment: I raised it as a github issue on the Magento repo but got no where https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35415